# React.js: Why is the component state not changing and why is the component not re-rendering once component state changes?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, amazon-web-services, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

I am having an issue with the code below.  When I setState of the term variable the component re-renders and the value is shown on the page.  However, when the facebook user is logged in and the responseFacebook function is run the setState is not working and the component is not re-rendered.  I can not get the state to contain the access tokens.  I am seeing the response from Facebook and AWS, but I just can't store the toekens.  Maybe I am doing this all wrong. I am very new to react (2 days), the facebook SDK, the AWS SDK, and authorization in general.  Please, any advice?

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './Home.css';
import FacebookLogin from 'react-facebook-login';
import graph from 'fb-react-sdk';
import config from '../config.js';

import {
  CognitoUserPool,
  AuthenticationDetails,
  CognitoUser
} from 'amazon-cognito-identity-js';

var AWS = require('aws-sdk');
var request = require('request');

graph.setAppSecret(APPSECRET);

class Home extends Component {

  constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.responseFacebook = this.responseFacebook.bind(this);

        this.state = { 
            term: '',
            accessTokenFB: '',
            accessTokenAWS: ''
        };

        console.log('We are here 1: ' + this.state.accessTokenFB);
        if(this.state.accessTokenFB != null){
          console.log('We are here 2');
          this.getFriends();
        }

    }

    componentDidUpdate(){
         console.log("This component updated!!!!");
    }

    getFriends(){
      var options = {
        timeout:  3000,
        pool:     { maxSockets:  Infinity },
        headers:  { connection:  "keep-alive" }
      };

      graph
        .setOptions(options)
        .get("me/friends", function(err, res) {
          console.log(res);
      });
    }


    responseFacebook(response) {
      console.log(response);
      console.log(response.accessToken);
      graph.setAccessToken(response.accessToken);

      this.getFriends();

      console.log('TokenFB: ' + this. accessTokenFB);
      console.log('TokenFB: ' + response.accessToken);



      // Check if the user logged in successfully.
      if (response.accessToken) {

        console.log('You have an FB token.');

        AWS.config.region = 'us-east-1';

        // Add the Facebook access token to the Cognito credentials login map.
        AWS.config.credentials = new AWS.CognitoIdentityCredentials({
          IdentityPoolId: config.cognito.IDENTITY_POOL_ID,
          Logins: {
            'graph.facebook.com': response.accessToken
          }
        });

        // Obtain AWS credentials
        AWS.config.credentials.get(function(data){
            // Access AWS resources here.
            console.log("Logged into aws...");
            console.log("TokenAWS: " + AWS.config.credentials.sessionToken);
        });

        this.setState({ 
          accessTokenFB: response.accessToken,
          accessTokenAWS: AWS.config.credentials.sessionToken
        });

        //console.log(AWS.config.credentials.sessionToken);

      } else {
        console.log('There was a problem logging you in.');
      }
    }

  render() {
    console.log('TokenFB: ' + this. accessTokenFB);
    return (
      <div className="Home">
        <div className="lander">

          <FacebookLogin
            appId="**********"
            autoLoad={true}
            fields="name,email,picture"
            callback={this.responseFacebook}
          />
          <a href="#" onClick={event => this.setState({term:"5"})} >click</a><br/>
          Term: {this.state.term}<br/>
          TokenAWS: {this.state.accessTokenAWS}
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Home;
```

Comment: Idk man, this code looks fine to me. You can add a `componentDidUpdate` method to see if your state is actually being updated or not.

Comment: Well, I can see the onclick action taking place.  I have also placed a componentDidUpdate which works great for the onClick. That works. On intial page load the facebook login takes place and I can see the correct values for the tokens within the console. However, the component is not re-rendered and componentDidUpdate is not run.

Comment: Do you see `You have an FB token.` logged in the console?

Comment: Yes, I just did that for testing because it is never changing the state. Obviously, the token is empty on first run. When the response happens it is correct in the console. I then would expect the component to re-render, but it does not.

Comment: I am currently working around this with local and session storage.